# how to create HTML table inside the script in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have javascript api to send email in which I can also use html, so I am creating table inside it but it is not working and tables does not show. Here is my code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#commandEmail1").click(function() {
            presenter.command("emailSend",{
                "toEmail": "imran.hussain@celeritas-solutions.com",
                "toName": "Celeritas",
                "subject": "email test",
                "body": "Single Attachment",
                "bodyHtml":"<table width="200" border="1"><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td> </tr><tr> <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td> </tr></table>",
                 "attachments": [""]
            });
            return false;
        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use single quotes inside double quotes

```
"<table width='200'...
```

or you can replace double quotes inside with `&quot;`

Answer (score 0):

Code should be like this..
You have used double quotes..

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$("#commandEmail1").click(function() {


presenter.command("emailSend",{
    "toEmail": "imran.hussain@celeritas-solutions.com",
    "toName": "Celeritas",
    "subject": "email test",
    "body": "Single Attachment",


 "bodyHtml":"<table width='200' border='1'><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td> </tr><tr> <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td> </tr></table>
              ",
       "attachments": [""]
         });
     return false;
         });
         })
```